# SwiftUI - No exact matches in call to initialiser

Tags: swiftui

As the title suggests I'm getting an error in the below code (related to the loop when trying to build.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var testImages = ["Image1", "Image2", "Image3"].shuffled()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0...2) { number in
                Image(self.testImages[number])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`0...2` is a type of `ClosedRange`, but `ForEach` only works with `Range` types.

Try changing the loop to use the `..<` range syntax:

```swift
ForEach(0..<3) { number in
  Image(self.testImages[number])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the code below, this will count the number of elements in the array, at least you won't need to modify the number each time you add or remove elements in your array

```
ForEach(0..<Int(testImages.count), id:\.self) { number in
  Image(self.testImages[number])
}
```

Comment: ForEach isn't a for loop, this will crash when accessing the array subscript when it changes.

Comment: I tested the code before posting it and everything works perfectly